# How to enable sound on Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to use a Windows Azure Virtual Machine as an development machine. I want to enable sound on that machine in order to hear the event sounds (errors, warrnings etc) and listen to the music from last.fm.

Is it possible to have sound on the Azure virtual machines?

I tried: http://www.wikihow.com/Hear-Audio-from-the-Remote-PC-when-Using-Remote-Desktop but it does not help.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 / Windows Server 2013

Comment: I'm assuming Windows, but to be sure, what OS are you using?

Comment: Yes. I have this issue on each Windows edition. Any experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable Remote Desktop Services as in below link and Configure Client Experience and tick 'Audio and Video Playback". You may also need to install Desktop Experience feature if it is not installed.

http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2012/07/enabling-remote-desktop-services-in.html

Comment: Thanks for comment. I do not know if my question is still 'valid'. I have posted it on 2013 and have not been using Azure since then :)

Comment: You're welcome bro .. actually yes it is still valid .. I have run into the same issue you posted just 2 days ago and figure out how to solve it using the link above ..

Answer (score 2):

Try starting the Windows Audio service (hit start, type "services"). I think the Windows Audio service is set to manual by default in Azure virtual machines so you could change it to "Automatic" so your sound remain on even after a reboot. No guarantees on how good the sound will be though, depending on your connection YMMV.

Comment: Yes this works for me (running Windows 2012 Server on Azure VM). Are you able to test this with local on-premise servers just to make sure it's not an issue on your client machine?

Comment: On Azure VM with Win10,the Windows Audio service is started, but no audio playback/recording devices available in Control Panel->Manage audio devices. Any hint?

Comment: It works, but only when connected to the VM. If you want to leave the audio playing (for a stream, for example), the audio device is shut down when the remote connection ends.