# Azure VM throws Transport error while recognizing microphone

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-virtual-machine, microphone, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to make the Microsoft Cognitive speech work in my Azure VM. I get the below error when the code tries to reach the point to recognize microphone. The same code works perfectly in my actual desktop but the error occurs only in the VM.

*--- Start speech recognition using microphone with ShortPhrase mode in en-US language ----
--- Error received by OnConversationErrorHandler() ---

Error code: -2147023728

Error text: Transport error*

I tried all possible options mentioned in most of the internet articles but no luck

[How to enable sound on Windows Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022620/how-to-enable-sound-on-windows-azure-vm)

http://oakleafblog.blogspot.in/2012/07/enabling-remote-desktop-services-in.html

Is there any specific settings check should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a connection issue to the server.

There are 2 types of Microsoft Cognitive Speech.

1. Using HTTPRequest to send audio data
2. Using Websocket to stream audio data

If you are using websocket, then :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol

Maybe there is a problem with Azure VM (since Azure VM are built to be secure). Make sure your Azure VM are not blocking the network. Websocket-type connection are using 2 network request, which is **HTTPRequest** and **WebSocket**.

The summary of the api reference are :

1. The HTTPRequest is to get the token from : https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken (make sure you allow your Azure VM to allow connection to this site)
2. After getting the token, the client have to send HTTPRequest to begin websocket handshake, the client should receive 101 code (Switching Protocol) and you can begin the websocket handshake.
   The websocket connection link will be **wss://xxxxxxxxxx.api.cris.ai/speech/recognition/[dictation/shortphrase]/cognitiveservices/v1**

> **Make sure your Azure VM allows both connection.**

If you only use HTTPRequest, you just have to make sure that your VM allows to connect to the Token server and the cognitive speech server.

Comment: Hi Vincent - Thank you for sharing your inputs. I am not using web socket connection and trying to run the below sample from github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows . Here i am getting the transport error in CreateMicrophoneRecoClient method